# After Windows 10 Update, Login Password Not Working

Tags: passwords, windows-10

I upgraded to Windows 10 and was enjoying the new software. I shut down and the next day when I turned on the computer it asked for the password. I did not have a password on the desktop. So even though I wrote down the password for the Microsoft account it says that it is wrong and after some attempts it locks me out and doesn't show the password option button or the hint that I wrote.

Comment: When logging in, is it trying to log in with a Microsoft account or a local account? You can tell this by looking at the username when attempting to log in. If it's like username@domain.com it's a Microsoft account. If it doesn't have an `@` symbol in the user name, it's trying to log in with a local account.

Comment: If you have a hotmail.com or msn.com - the password should be the same..  However, I did run into an issue where I changed the password for my mail, but it did not update the password for drive.live.com (formerly Skydrive)..

Comment: It's probably the Keyboard layout. If you have multiple languages you just have to go to your traditional layout.

Comment: Enable the On Screen Keyboard and type the password if you are not sure. Otherwise click the eye icon after typing the password to verify if it's the keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today.

Disconnecting the ethernet cable resolved the issue. (Surprising, right?)